# Multiplying parenthesis to get a polynomial in python

Tags: python, physics, numerical-methods

I was asked to do the newton polynomial interpolation and I was able to write the main code. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial
But there is still one small thing that I am not able to get around since a couple of days, after reading I found a way to do it using Sympy, but I am not allowed to use anything other than basic numpy. 
Now my problem is that I trying to multiply something like this

p(x)=j(x-q)(x-w)(x-e)+k(x-w)(x-e)+l(x-e)+d

to get this p(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d , so I amlooking for the polynomial coefficients a,b,c,d

for example:

p(x)=5-7(x+1)+9(x+1)(x)-7(x+1)(x)(x-1)=-7x³+9x²+9x-2

of course I am looking for the general case, not only for ploynomials from third degree. 
Any tip would be much appreciated, I am really stuck at this since a couple of days. 
and Sorry for the sloppy writing of notation, but it seems stackoverflow doesn't accept latex and I am not able to post a picture because I don't have rhe required reputation. (if there is other solutuions to post it properly please tell me and I'll just post it again)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the polynomial provided as a string? Give an example input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll rewrite the equation as

c<sub>3</sub>(x-r<sub>3</sub>)(x-r<sub>2</sub>)(x-r<sub>1</sub>)+c<sub>2</sub>(x-r<sub>2</sub>)(x-r<sub>1</sub>)+c<sub>1</sub>(x-r<sub>1</sub>)+c<sub>0</sub>

Next, note that this is equivalent to:

((c<sub>3</sub>(x-r<sub>3</sub>)+c<sub>2</sub>)(x-r<sub>2</sub>)+c<sub>1</sub>)(x-r<sub>1</sub>)+c<sub>0</sub>

You can multiply it out if you want to check.

So in general, you can do:

```
poly = np.poly1d([c[n]])
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    poly = poly*np.poly1d([1,-r[n]])+np.poly1d([n-1])
```

You can probably replace `np.poly1d([c[n]])` with just `c[n]` and `np.poly1d([c[n-1]])` with just `c[n-1]`, if you're willing to trust the coercion to work properly

Comment: thanks a lot man, it works like magic, I have done the same but in a much more complicated way and didn't even get meaningful answers. You saved the day, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to represent a polinomial as an array where `a[0]..a[n]` where a[i] is the constant that you multipliy (x^i). The function will be something like `p(x) = a[0] + a[1]*x + a[2]* (x**2)...`.

Now to add two polinomials in this representation you just need to pad the shorter one with 0s and add the values at matching indices.

If you want to multiply a polinomial by k*(x**z) you need to multiply every value by k and insert z zeros in front( `a[0:0] = [0.] * z`).

Using these two operations you can resolve the equation and get the coefficients you want.

Comment: You not only need to multiply a polynomial with a constant but also with another polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying two polynomials `x(x-1)` is the same as convolving their coefficients:

```
# x     => [1, 0]
# (x-1) => [1, -1]
numpy.convolve([1, 0], [1, -1])  # [1, -1, 0] => x^2 - x + 0
```

This means you can solve the problem using

```
import numpy

def mult(a, b):
    """
    Polynomial multiplication is simply a convolution
    """
    return numpy.convolve(a, b)

def add(a, b):
    """
    Addition is a bit complex as a and b may have different lengths.
    Simply prepend zeros to the shorter one
    """

    if len(a) < len(b):
        a = numpy.insert(a, 0, [0] * (len(b) - len(a)))
    if len(b) < len(a):
        b = numpy.insert(b, 0, [0] * (len(a) - len(b)))

    return a + b


# p(x)=5-7(x+1)+9(x+1)(x)-7(x+1)(x)(x-1)=-7x³+9x²+9x-2
add(
    add(
        numpy.array([5]),
        mult([-7], [1, 1]),
    ),
    add(
        mult([9], mult([1, 1], [1, 0])),
        mult([-7], mult([1, 1], mult([1, 0], [1, -1])))
    )
)
```

yields

```
array([-7,  9,  9, -2])  # => -7x^3 + 9x^2 + 9x - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`, we have access to the `poly1d` object. With that, `j(x-q)(x-w)(x-e)+k(x-w)(x-e)+l(x-e)+d` is equivalent to:

```
In [ ]: j, q, w, e, k, w, l, d = range(1, 9)
   ...: poly1 = j*np.poly1d([-q, -w, -e], r=1)
   ...: poly2 = k*np.poly1d([-w, -e], r=0)
   ...: poly3 = l*np.poly1d([-e])
   ...: poly = poly1 + poly2 + poly3 + d
   ...: print(poly)
   3      2
1 x + 12 x + 14 x + 8
```